# Stop Iframe Refresh/Reload Loop When using Onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**EDIT** *I Found the solution*! credit goes entirely to the assistance I received from Mixel. For those who find themselves in the same predicament of needing to pull a div from an iframe without using onload here is the entire working code that I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Main page</title>
<style type="text/css">#hiddenframe {display:none;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var myUrl = "test.html" 
    document.frames['hiddenframe'].location.href = myUrl;   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent-div"></div>
<iframe id="hiddenframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Child Page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Child Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    parent.document.getElementById('parent-div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('daughter-div').innerHTML;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="daughter-div">
This is the Child Div!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you once again to Mixel for his help and patience in finding a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you reload hiddenframe in onload handler. Reloading triggers onload event, then onload handler reloads hiddenframe. And this happens again and again...

**Edit:**
May be I do not understand what you want to do in your code, but if you want to load iframe when parent window is loaded you need this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('hiddenframe').setAttribute('src', 'test.html');
}
```

And there is window.onload handler of test.html page:

```
window.onload = function () {
    parent.document.getElementById('parent-div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('daughter-div').innerHTML;
}
```

**Edit2:**

That's html of main page:

```
<div id="parent-div"></div>
<iframe id="hiddenframe">
</iframe>
```

And that's test.html:

```
<div id="daughter-div">
Child div!
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution stopped the iframe reloading, but now I am not getting the contents of the div from the iframe to load into the parent-div

Comment: I changed divs id when i tested code. Now it must work. It works in IE, Chrome (only under web server, if I open main page right from explorer Chrome give a message in debugging console that pages not in the same domain).

Comment: Your solution worked! I had merely implemented it wrong initially, thank you very much for your help